# Put a query to go to a file from a list, Microsoft Graph API Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph API for SharePoint. For the moment, my http query can get the site to list and see items. One of my items is a file and it's id is 1. How do you modify the query to get this item.

My query for the moment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`

Comment: Can this api help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TinyWang but i need to go in my file not to update him

Comment: all apis listed here... could you plse check them？ https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzGH7.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET List item endpoint in Graph API:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http